# HTML Date Input not showing date using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs

I am working on hybrid application using AngularJS and Angular 8. I am using datepicker to show date which is fetched from API but the problem the problem is if I use input type as **"text"** then it shows the date but if I use input type as **"date"** then it shows only **dd/mm/yyyy**. I have tried everything but all in vain. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**code**

**date is visible when input type is "text"**

```
<div class="datepicker-cont-wrap">
                        <div class="datepicker-wrap input-group">
                            <input uib-datepicker type="text" class="form-control"
                                   id="date_dead_line"
                                   placeholder="dd MM YYYY"
                                   value="{{(glPlmAsmt.data.deadline_time*1000) | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}"
                                   is-open = 'false'
                            >
                            <button type="button" class="btn gl-datepicker-btn"
                                    ng-click="glPlmAsmt.openDeadLineDate()">
                                <i class="glicon-date"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**date is not visible when input type is "date"**

```
                    <div class="datepicker-cont-wrap">
                        <div class="datepicker-wrap input-group">
                            <input uib-datepicker type="date" class="form-control"
                                   id="date_dead_line"
                                   placeholder="dd MM YYYY"
                                   value="{{(glPlmAsmt.data.deadline_time*1000) | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}"
                                   is-open = 'false'
                            >
                            <button type="button" class="btn gl-datepicker-btn"
                                    ng-click="glPlmAsmt.openDeadLineDate()">
                                <i class="glicon-date"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image: date is displayed]

I need to display the date in dd MMM yyyy format but instead of date value it is showing only dd/mm/yyyy

[image: date does not get displayed]

Comment: It seems like a "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" type thing. Where the answer is "Don't do that". If `type="date"` doesn't work, but `type="text"` does, use `type="text"`.

Comment: Wild guess - whatever text/format `{{(glPlmAsmt.data.deadline_time*1000) | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}` generates is not what a standard date input expects?  I mean ... what else could it be!? :-)

Comment: Heretic Monkey i need to make date input shows date picker on click to change date which doesn't happen if input type is text

Comment: Don't Panic: the above code is giving timestamp which i am trying to convert to date in dd MMM yyyy format , for example the above code should produce date as 31 Jan 2024 which i am getting from server as response and it is showing in console also

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date:

> Note: The displayed date format will differ from the actual value —
> the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's
> browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

The value you're using (`{{(glPlmAsmt.data.deadline_time*1000) | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}`) is obviously not in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, so it won't show correctly.

Why do you need to have a date input anyway? It generates its own datepicker which most likely would conflict with the UI Boostrap datepicker. If it works with a text input, just use a text input.

Comment: José A. Zapata : the thing is that using input type text it shows the date but on clicking it doesn't show date picker to allow me to choose date.

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma I don't quite remember how the UI Bootstrap datepicker works, but I think you need to click in the little calendar button for the datepicker to show up. If that doesn't work for you, try with a plain date input (no uib-datepicker) and see how it works.